# Textarea reduce its size when the website is opened on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a website in which i have used textarea to show output. The website is respnsive and
also it is running fine on my laptop browser and fine responsiveness but the problem happens when i open the website on my phone the textarea got too small but other elements are working fine.

Look at these two photos :-
[image: Working fine in desktop]

[image: Now look at the textarea when the site is open on phone]

Here is the repo: [github](https://github.com/masterujjval/Infix-Postfix-Web)

The code is so lengthy so i'm including only necessary line of code:

```
<p id="textarea">Postfix expression: </p>
      
      <textarea name="" id="answer" rows="1" cols="25" disabled>
      
    </textarea>
```

```
textarea{
    resize:none;
    
    background: black;
    outline : none;
    margin: 1% 0;
    border : 1px solid blueviolet;
    
    color: lavender;
    height : 3.1vh;
    width: 215px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

after using media query for phone screen:

```
input,textarea{
        width:63vw;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

So is there any way to solve this issue happening with textarea whenever the site is opened on the phone?
The textarea should have same height and width like the above input tag.
Can't able to figure out the issue happening with textarea.

Comment: I think you should change `height: vh` to something else like `px, rem ` etc.

Comment: But it is working fine on my laptop but whenver i opening the site on phone(using media query already did that) the issue appear

Comment: I think it's something conflicting in .css file... Maybe in 'margin-top: 65px;'

Comment: can you share your project live code?

Comment: To clarify: "vh" means percentage of the browser height. Of course it looks differently on your phone because the viewport has a different height. Just use `min-height: 30px;` for the textarea or something like that.

Comment: not working on my laptop, I'm checking your [Github Page](https://masterujjval.github.io/Infix-Postfix-Web/)

Answer (score 0):

It's now working by changing the height to pixels and changing the height the container.
The overall container height that is in `px` was not sufficient so I just increased the `px` and the problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).